# Book about groups of kids with object powers

Tags: story-identification, books

A few years ago I read a book where a kid (I believe in first person) was part of a group of chosen kids. The main character entered a room (in an alleyway?) where he was supposed to choose an object special to him. The main character saw a floating Earth that mimicked reality (water felt cool, the grass fresh smell, air breeze, n/s poles).
He ended up choosing a special box of some sort.
The other kids already chose their objects.

Another kid was a girl who had a necklace to go through objects. These monsters who can copy abilities copied the girls abilities and chased her in the ground when she turned off her powers and killed one of the, inciting rage for the others. There were 3 of these I believe. They were a threat throughout the whole story.

Hardback Book in English, I don't remember the specific year I read it

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please see our [guide on how to ask a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936) and [edit] your post with any additional details you remember.

Comment: Do you remember if the book was marketed as YA? Paperback? Hardback? EBook? Were they part of a mystic organization? Mutants? Demigods? Did they all go into the same room and see the same things? Were the monsters that copy abilities a common threat or was it just that one chapter? Do you remember if they were American, Japanese, French? White, black, First People? Young kids? Adolescents? Teenagers?

Comment: Thank you for editing so many details in! It really does help.

Comment: of course, i will try to add in any more things I remember